# SEO-оптимизация агрегатора

Tags: seo

Пишу сайт-агрегатор, собирающий ссылки на статьи по заданной тематике с других сайтов. Естественным образом, на сайте практически одни внешние ссылки, на что ругаются SEO-чекеры — мол, сайт бесполезен и не содержит уникального контента.
Возникает вопрос: а как вообще, в принципе, можно продвигать сайт-агрегатор, если он по определению содержит практически одни внешние ссылки?
Может, есть какие-то особые атрибуты для ссылок (для внешних сейчас использую noopener noreferrer nofollow), особые мета-теги или еще что-то?..